# json.dumps not forming escape characters correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to programatically build the json payload for a graphQL API request. The payload should look like (note the escape characters in "quote":

```
{
    "query": "query InstrumentRefData($ObjectList: [String!]) {\n  EDFInstrument(objectIds: $ObjectList) {\n    ObjectId\n    Reference {\n      AssetClassId\n    }\n  }\n}", 
    "variables": {"ObjectList": ["8590920808", "21647871436"]}
}
```

I have this stored in a dictionary (ED_Query), and am trying to convert the contents of the dictionary to a JSON string using json.dumps(ED_Quote), but my request fails due to a malformed query, and looking in debug mode in Visual Studio Code, I can see that the escape characters in "query" are not formed correctly - they are \\n rather than \n.

```
{
"query": "query InstrumentRefData($ObjectList: [String!]) {\\n  EDFInstrument(objectIds: $ObjectList) {\\n    ObjectId\\n    Reference {\\n      AssetClassId\\n      Cfi\\n      InstrumentStatus\\n    }\\n  }\\n}", 
"variables": {"ObjectList": ["8590920808", "21647871436"]}
}
```

This used to work - but I've obviously changed something, and now I'm stuck with what appears to be malformed escape characters.

I'm running this in Python 3.8.2 64 bit, on Visual Studio Code 1.56.2 on a Mac running Catalina 10.15.7.

Can anyone point me to what I have changed that is causing this?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: This is correct. `\n` in a JSON string would be invalid. You can see this if you try to load it. `json.loads('{"a": "\n"}')`

Comment: @blueteeth But your example there doesn't use the escape sequence `\n` in a JSON string; it uses a newline character in a JSON string. As far as I know, using the escape sequence `\n` in JSON is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Paul_G I have a couple of suggestions for things to try. Run Python 3.8.2 in a terminal and try evaluating `json.dumps({"query": "\n"})` and then `print(json.dumps({"query": "\n"}))`. See what each of those things prints out. Then write a piece of code that does `x = json.dumps({"query": "\n"})` and then look at the value of `x` in your debugger. What are the results from all of this? Are they what you were expecting?

Comment: @TannerSwett - In Terminal, this is what was returned - json.dumps({"query":"\n"}) returned '{"query": "\\n"}' and print(json.dumps({"query":"\n"})) returned '{"query":"\n"}. Looking at 'x=json.dumps({"query":"\n"}) in the debugger shows '{"query": "\\n"}', so the debug mode seems to match what the pure json.dumps returned in the terminal - the problematic '\\n' - At least this is consistent, so I guess I need to try and unpick whatever changes I made. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What I've seen so far is consistent with the hypothesis that the output from json.dumps actually *contains* the escape sequence `\n` (which, I'm pretty sure, is exactly what you want), but Visual Studio Code is *displaying* that as `\\n`. However, that doesn't explain the second code block you pasted (which looks partly like a piece of JSON shown verbatim, and partly like a piece of JSON which has been escaped), nor why your request is being rejected.

Comment: @TannerSwett I’m beginning to think this is a problem upstream of me. The API I’m calling has a developer tool that lets me paste the api data request  into a UI and see the results, if I include a print(json.dumps(ED_Query)) statement in my code, run it, and then paste the resulting text into the developer tool, the tool access the text and runs as expected. Will check with the API development owner.

Comment: @TannerSwett I don't get the distinction you're making. If you try to load a json string containing only `\n` you get a `JSONDecodeError`. If you escape it, you can load it, and then when you print it in Python, it prints a newline. This is the reverse of what OP wants, but the same rules about parsing still hold. See `print(json.loads('{"a": "a\nb"}')["a"])` vs `print(json.loads('{"a": "a\\nb"}')["a"])`

Comment: @blueteeth "If you try to load a json string containing only \n you get a JSONDecodeError." – No, I don't think that's correct. If I use `json.loads` to load the literal string `"\n"` (that is, the string which contains a double quote, backslash, lowercase n, and double quote), then the function successfully returns a string containing a newline character. You can see this by evaluating `json.loads(r'"\n"')`, or by evaluating `json.loads(input())` and typing `"\n"` (including the quotation marks).

Comment: @blueteeth The example of `json.loads('{"a": "a\\nb"}'` is a little misleading, because at first glance, it looks like the content of the string you're passing to `json.loads` is `{"a": "a\\nb"}` (verbatim, with two backslashes), but the content is actually `{"a": "a\nb"}` (verbatim, with one backslash). What causes a JSONDecodeError is if you give `json.loads` a string which, instead of containing the escape sequence `\n`, contains an actual newline character in between quotation marks (which is what `json.loads('{"a": "a\nb"}'` does).

Comment: Exactly. That's why I don't think there's an issue here. What Paul_G is seeing in debug mode is effectively the string `\n`, which is correct. What Paul_G says they wanted was the literal newline character, which they can't have.

Comment: the reason you see double slash in the console is because the __repr__ is being called for objects.  it doesnt truly have double back slash..u can tell this by explicitly printing.  u can also write the json to a file and open it..u will not see back slashes.